# Get practical maxspeed for openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm trying to get the practical maxspeed for all ways in a bounding box:

Documentation for maxspeed practical:

https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/maxspeed%3Apractical#overview

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed:practical

```html
res = api.query("""
way[highway](around:500,52.52,13.40)["maxspeed"]
;(._;>;);
out meta;
""")
```

replacing ["maxspeed"] with ["maxspeed:practical"] doesn't seem to work.
What am I missing?

Comment: Why is this question tagged nominatim whereas your code looks like Overpass API?

Answer (score 1):

> replacing ["maxspeed"] with ["maxspeed:practical"] doesn't seem to
>   work. What am I missing?

Nothing is wrong with your query. The roads in your area just don't have a `maxspeed:practical` tag. See [this example](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/P7g) where `maxspeed:practical` tags are present.

Currently there are over [11 million ways in OSM with a `maxspeed` tag](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/maxspeed) but only [22 thousand are tagged with `maxspeed:practical`](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/maxspeed%3Apractical). Many of them don't need this tag since their practical speed limit is probably above the legal limit. For others this tag just hasn't been added yet.

OpenStreetMap is mainly improved by volunteers. Feel free to [join and add this information yourself](https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/).